# Regex expression minimum length of the word

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for an expression that removes numbers when the word is longer than 8 characters.

For example:

"Python300" -> "Python"

"Python37" -> "Python37"

I use this expression `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=.*[0-9]).*$` but select all.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Can't it be a [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) `if`?

```
import re
max_length = 9
s = 'Python300'
s = s if len(s) < max_length else re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', s)
```

Comment: Or without regex: `s = s if len(s) < max_length else s.rstrip('0123456789')`

Comment: @JvdV yes, even better (assuming the digits are always in the end)

Answer (score 0):

You can match using this regex to remove all **trailing digits** from words with length greater than `8`:

```bash
\b(?=\w{9,})(\w+?)\d+\b
```

and replace using:

```
r'\1'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1DnKJv/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?=\w{9,})`: Make sure word has 9 or more characters
- `(\w+?)`: Match 1+ word chars in capture group #1 (lazy match)
- `\d+`: Match 1+ trailing digits
- `\b`: Word boundary

**Code:**

```py
import re

arr = ['Python300', 'Python37']

for s in arr:
    print (re.sub(r'\b(?=\w{9,})(\w+?)\d+\b', r'\1', s))
```

**Output:**

```bash
Python
Python37
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the regex expression but it didn't work.

I have put a code in pyspark so that it can be replicated.

Thanks anyway

```
a = ['python37', 'python300', '19Covid', '1234Spark', 'spark-2-python']
b = ['python37', 'python', '19Covid', 'Spark', 'spark--python']


impacto = pd.DataFrame (zip(a,b), columns = ['input', "expected"])
spark.createDataFrame(impacto) \
    .withColumn("result", sf.regexp_replace(sf.col("input"), r"\b(?=\w{9,})(\w+?)\d+\b", r'\1')) \
    .show()
```

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|         input|     expected|        result|
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|      python37|     python37|      python37|
|     python300|       python|             1|
|       19Covid|      19Covid|       19Covid|
|     1234Spark|        Spark|     1234Spark|
|spark-2-python|spark--python|spark-2-python|
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```